# Conditionally display blocks when an attribute exists in my object in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My Vue data object structure is as follows:

[image]

Only when errors occur on my form, the `addPersonForm.errors` object is populated as follows:

[image]

Now in my page I am trying to display conditional error tags and classes when the `addPersonForm.errors.name` is populated by doing the following:

```
<form action="{{ route('business.queue.add') }}" method="POST" id="manual-add">
    <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error' : addPersonForm.errors }">
        <label for="add-person-name">Customer Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="add-person-name" v-model="addPersonForm.fields.name">
        <template v-if="addPersonForm.errors">
            <small class="form-text text-danger">@{{ addPersonForm.errors.name[0] }}</small>
        </template>
        <template v-else>
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Name will be displayed internally and to the customer</small>
        </template>

    </div>
```

When loading the page, vue throws an error saying `Cannot read property 'name' of null`. I suspect this is because the `addPersonForm.errors` is empty on load.
Can someone assist me on how to correctly show the conditional tags if the `name` attribute exists?

(I'm aware the `name` attribute is an array, I'm only interested if there is an error, if if there is then display the first one).

Comment: FYI, you can put your `v-if` / `v-else` directly on the `<small>` tags. There's no need to use `<template>` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v-if="addPersonForm.errors"` should be enough to prevent the error from occurring. Are you sure it's this part of the code that's triggering the problem?

In any case, you can ensure you won't get an error by using [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```html
                                          <!-- note the "?"  -->
<small class="form-text text-danger">@{{ addPersonForm.errors?.name[0] }}</small>
```

Comment: Hi Phil, using `addPersonForm.errors` wouldn't be enough as I need to only display error template for this particular field. In the wider code there are a number of fields which is why I specificall specify the `name` attribute (which is the field it relates to). Using your optional chaining has worked however.

Comment: In that case, your question does not contain enough information to accurately describe your problem